# PHP Search Array values in Text and Replace - Stock Tickers

Tags: php

I have an array of most traded stock tickers as below:

```
$tickers = ["TSLA", "AAPL", "ABNB", "AMC", "BABA", "AMZN", "TWTR", "MSFT", "SHOP", "NFLX"];
```

I would like to search text for occurrences of a ticker symbol present in tickers array and replace that occurrence with the $ ticker. Here is an expected result.

```
$string = "Among the best traded stocks this year, TSLA, AMZN and SHOP have been rallying today. NFLX has however dropped as well as ABNB";
```

The result should be:

```
$string = "Among the best traded stocks this year, $TSLA, $AMZN and $SHOP have been rallying today. $NFLX has however dropped as well as $ABNB";
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace` with a back-reference to any matched items like so:

```
$tickers = ["TSLA", "AAPL", "ABNB", "AMC", "BABA", "AMZN", "TWTR", "MSFT", "SHOP", "NFLX"];
$string = "Among the best traded stocks this year, TSLA, AMZN and SHOP have been rallying today. NFLX has however dropped as well as ABNB - ignore ALIBABA";

/*
    The pattern is ALL items from the ticker
    - separated by the pipe char. In this case
    the pattern delimiter is simply the @ char

    \b denotes a "Word Boundary"
*/
$pttn=sprintf('@(\b%s\b)@',implode('\b|\b',$tickers ) );

/*
    The back-reference is $1 and is preceded by
    the desired character ~ in this case $
*/
echo preg_replace( $pttn,'$$1', $string );
```

Which yields:

```
Among the best traded stocks this year, $TSLA, $AMZN and $SHOP have been rallying today. 
$NFLX has however dropped as well as $ABNB - ignore ALIBABA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tickers = ["TSLA", "AAPL", "ABNB", "AMC", "BABA", "AMZN", "TWTR", "MSFT", "SHOP", "NFLX"];
$string = "Among the best traded stocks this year, TSLA, AMZN and SHOP have been rallying today. NFLX has however dropped as well as ABNB";
foreach ($tickers as $iT) {
$string = str_replace($iT, '$' . $iT, $string);
}
```

result string should be
Among the best traded stocks this year, $TSLA, $AMZN and $SHOP have been rallying today. $NFLX has however dropped as well as $ABNB

Comment: Warning, this replaces larger words containing the ticker, e.g. `ALIBABA` would become `ALI$BABA`.

Comment: Yes. Same as when I added "T" to the tickers array for AT & T, a string with Twitter (ticker "TWTR") would result to $$TW$TR

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$tickers = ["TSLA", "AAPL", "ABNB", "AMC", "BABA", "AMZN", "TWTR", "MSFT", "SHOP", "NFLX"];
$string = "Among the best traded stocks this year, TSLA, AMZN and SHOP have been rallying today. NFLX has however dropped as well as ABNB";
$words = explode(" ",$string);
$newString = "";
foreach($words as $word){
    if(in_array($word,$tickers))
        $newString .= "$".$word." ";
    else
        $newString .= $word." ";
}
echo $newString;
```

in my soultion a sentences split to words and check if them exist in array or not